# Why do some words have "X" as a substitute?

Tags: abbreviations

Why do people sometimes substitute x for letters in a word?

**Examples**:

- Xing
- Xmas
- Xfr

Comment: A couple of others: **tx** = transmit and **rx** = receive, both indicating a crossing of a message or signal.

Comment: or eXchanging of messages (Rx,Tx) or Transformers (Trans=cross over) or X-ForMeR or XFMR

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In those three examples, there are three different, albeit related, reasons:

- **Xing** = Crossing.  The "X" replaces "Cross" because an X is a cross.
- **Xmas** = Christmas.  The "X" replaces "Christ" because the cross is a symbol of Jesus and because X (really Chi) is an initial for "Christ" in Greek (Χριστός).
- **Xfr** = Transfer.  The "X" replaces the prefix "trans-" as it implies a crossing of something.

They are all abbreviations.  I would be surprised if the origin of "Xing" wasn't in street signs, where "crossing" would be a long word to print to be able to read at a distance. I've more often seen "Xfr" as "Xfer"; it is used in electronic communications as jargon.  I don't know the origin of "Xmas", but some people would have you believe that it's an effort to remove Christ from the holiday.  I would guess it is just another general abbreviation.

Comment: Probably shouldn't get into the whole "war on Christmas" thing, but I'd like to point out that I remember my mom explaining the X in Xmas to me when I was a little kid back in the early 70's. If its a nefarious plot, its a very old one.

Comment: _Xmas_ goes way back. Google Books quickly showed [this use](http://books.google.com/books?id=hHYdAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA223&dq=%22xmas%22&hl=en&ei=asBBTuomwuWIAte9xZcF&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CF0Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22xmas%22&f=false) published in 1791 but quoting a letter from 1719.

Comment: And the older *[X'temmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmas#History)* goes back to at least 1551.

Comment: @mgkrebbs: X as an abbreviation for Christ goes even further back than that: 16th century English church registers often wrote "Christopher" as *Xtopher* or similar. See for example: http://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/names/english/parishes/parishes.html -- I can't figure out how people add links to comments. It's not taking straight html.

Comment: @JPmiaou [Words for link]REMOVE_THIS_To_make_the_bracketed_text_a_link_to(THIS_URL). Oh, and +1 for pointing out that Xmas is not a demonic plot. Not to say anything about rampant consumerism...

Comment: Even though I know, intellectually, there is not a demonic plot at work in substituting "Christ" with "X" in the word "Christmas," I still refuse to abbreviate the word as Xmas.  I figure, in a literal sort of way, why take Christ out of Christmas?  "Am I so lazy that I can't take an extra 2.65 seconds to write the word "Christ?" I ask myself.

Comment: @JPmiaou Or, to put it more simply `[this](https://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/names/english/parishes/parishes.html)` becomes [this](https://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/names/english/parishes/parishes.html) (be sure to include the `https://` part). It's [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) syntax. As someone who grew up with "xmas" and even "chrimbo" being fairly commonplace, I find the idea that some people have come up with 'demonic plot' conspiracy theories quite hilarious. While Christian influence is very much eroding, the forces at work are undoubtedly human ones, not demonic ones.

Comment: @rhetorician While I agree it's unnecessarily lazy in the current era (and probably only continues to exist because it has a kind of novelty value), it made sense at the time it was introduced. Back then paper and ink were much more costly to produce, and text had to be copied by hand, so writers would look for ways to conserve paper and ink, thus giving rise to [scribal abbreviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation). (One Roman citizen (Tiro, a secretary and former slave) even invented [a kind of shorthand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes) around 60 BC.)

Comment: @Pharap: Interesting. Thanks for the information and links. Don

Comment: The X in "Xmas" is actually because "Christos" in Greek is spelled "Χριστός". It's literally Jesus's first initial in Greek. The first letter is actually a Greek "chi", not technically an English "x", but it looks pretty much the same. Any claims that this abbreviation is somehow a plot to "take Christ out of Christmas" have more to do with political propaganda than with any slight against Jesus by nonchristians. (Somehow, "Thou Shalt Not Bear False Witness Against Thy Neighbor" seems no longer in vogue these days, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 2):

Xmas is a specific case of using X to denote Christ, a practice that goes back many centuries.  One can look up further details, but essentially it's an initial.   Imagine if you were documenting the daily activities of the President of the United States, lots and lots of things Barack Obama said and did. Especially if you were writing it out with a quill pen, you might quickly start abbreviating using B to mean Barack Obama.  "Secret service guarding B cautioned. .."

Comment: Many such writing abbreviations were used when everything had to be written out by hand (like modern textspeak). "Y" for "th" is another example (as in "ye olde...") because an obsolete letter representing the sound th looked a bit like a y.

Comment: POTUS and SOTUS agree

Answer (score 1):

Several abbreviations including X came to common language from [Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code_abbreviations), most notably TX and RX for "Transmit" and "Receive". Other examples include VX for "Voice", NX for "Noise" and DX for "Distance".

Answer (score 0):

The X has, for like aeons, been used as a symbol representing the Christian cross. Like in Xmas, meaning the Christian-mas celebration. Other people, like coders, went to use them as a shorting for "crossing". Thus, "Xing"'s meaning would pretty much resemble to an "X-ing", a road cross, like "Will you stay there, or do you want more?" Remember the "Crossroads" movie casting Britney Spears? For more comprehensive information I'd recommend "see above". In case you are more courious, "XX" once stood for "crisscross" an expression that is, at least to my knowledge, pretty much widespread within the trans/a-gender community, while "XXX", until now, is a sweet way to express your love, because you are sooo like criss cross confused by your crush =)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The "X" is not just representing the Christian Cross. It's an initial: The X in "Xmas" is actually because "Christos" in Greek is spelled "Χριστός". It's literally Jesus's first initial in Greek. The first letter is actually a Greek "chi", not technically an English "x", but it looks pretty much the same.