# Abbreviation. Why *xmas*?

Tags: abbreviations, christmas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some words have “X” as a substitute?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37394/why-do-some-words-have-x-as-a-substitute)

I had seen abbreviations like sk8 (meanning skate, using *sk* and the number pronunciantion *eight*).

But why Christmas is abbreviated like ***xmas***?

*x* pronunciation is *ex* and *ex-mas* doesn't works.

Maybe is because the *x* looks like a cross but I don't know.

Someone can explain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmas):

> "Xmas" is a common abbreviation of the word "Christmas". It is sometimes pronounced /ˈɛksməs/, but it, and variants such as "Xtemass", originated as handwriting abbreviations for the typical pronunciation /ˈkrɪsməs/. The "-mas" part is from the Latin-derived Old English word for "Mass", while the "X" comes from the Greek letter Chi, which is the first letter of the Greek word Χριστός, translated as "Christ".
>
> There is a common misconception that the word Xmas is a secular attempt to remove the religious tradition from Christmas by taking the "Christ" out of "Christmas".

Comment: The original association of X may be from Χριστός, but it seems that the X = cross association is memetically more significant these days.