# Origin of word "xfered"

Tags: etymology, slang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some words have “X” as a substitute?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37394/why-do-some-words-have-x-as-a-substitute)

I came upon the word "xfered" recently. From what I gather, it means "transferred", and I believe it is used in computer-related areas. Am I correct and does anyone know the origin of this word?

Comment: @coleopterist: Thanks, that seems to answer my question. Although, I wonder which is more common, one "r" or two (i.e., `xferred` or `xfered`).

Comment: That would probably be xferred. You can get a rough idea by comparing the number of hits returned by Google Search.

Comment: Isn't the "word" for the twenty-fourth alphabet *X-Mas*? (Along with *Xylophone*). It's a more generic prefix used variously.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Kris, but your comment really doesn't seem to make  much sense.

Comment: @itsbruce It need not, to everyone, necessarily. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*xfer* has long been a popular contraction for transfer in computer networking; in the early days, many operating systems had severe (e.g. 8 letter) restrictions on the length of filenames and commands, which often compelled such abbreviations.  The earliest appearance of *xfer* in computing that I am aware of is connected to [FTP](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_FTPOverviewHistoryandStandards.htm), a network protocol which predates the public Internet, having been proposed as a [standard](http://ftpguide.com/history.htm) in 1971.  [WU-FTPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WU-FTPD), an early implementation of **FTP** developed at Washington University, stores details of file transfers in a file called [xferlog](http://www.wfms.org/wu-ftpd/docs/logging.html), whose format has become a standard among later implementations because of the large number of tools that were written to analyse and report on xferlog data.

Comment: Excellent, this was what I was looking for. It makes a lot more sense explaining why it is an abbreviation.

Comment: Great historical context +1

Comment: Re. "etymology", if there's any such thing with respect to *xfer(ed)*, see my comment at OP.

Answer (score 5):

The prefix *trans-* means *across*.

An X is a type of cross (one line is drawn *across* the other).

To replace *trans-* with an *x* is simply a short-hand that has gained currency.

Comment: I remember using X for "trans" this for notes I took in my classes, circa 1965.

Answer (score 1):

```
I came upon the word "xfered"...
```

This sentence is incorrect to the extent that '*xfered*' is not a word defined in standard English dictionaries. That makes any "etymology" irrelevant.

It is not necessarily a specific word used in technical literature as such.

[xferred](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=xferred)    **2 thumbs down**
Abbreviation of transferred.
*That car was xferred to New York*.

In using short forms, the prefix '*x*' is used to generally denote 'trans-' with any suitable word/ tail. This has been in practice for a very long time in the fields of physics, electronics, computer hardware and software. However, it is also sometimes similarly used for other prefixes, including as in 'xtal' for crystal, etc.

Note that this is a mere convenience practice and not a recognized short form for formal technical writing.

Comment: Not all words appear in dictionaries.

Comment: @JAM I don't know if anyone here on this post has said otherwise. :)