# How did "Christmas" end up being "Xmas"?

Tags: etymology, christmas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some words have “X” as a substitute?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37394/why-do-some-words-have-x-as-a-substitute)

I went to Online Etymology and this is what I found:

> "Christmas," 1551, X'temmas, wherein the X is an abbreviation for Christ in Christmas, from first letter of Greek Christos "Christ". The earlier way to abbreviate it was Xp- or Xr-, corresponding to "Chr-," and the form Xres mæsse for "Christmas" appears in the "Anglo-Saxon Chronicle" (c.1100).

But I fail to understand how did this transform happen? Mention in popular culture or books would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't remove the duplicate link. Thanks!